# Java - hide the string in JPasswordField

Tags: java, user-interface

I am trying to check the Password input. The password is already set, it is "123". Everything works fine but when I write the password into the Input box I can see what I wrote. I want to hide the password like ****. How can I fix this?

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    String password= "123";

    JPasswordField pf = new JPasswordField();

    String pw = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Bitte geben Sie das Passwort ein");

    if (pw.equals((password))) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"correct!");
    } else
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"False!");
}
```

Comment: Why are you opening a new input dialog instead of actually using the `JPasswordField`?

Comment: I tried to use it, but it does not work…@UnholySheep

Comment: "It does not work" is not a problem description. Though you seem to try to use a text field as a popup (which obviously doesn't work). But the [official tutorial for `JPasswordField`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/passwordfield.html) has [example code how to create your own](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/PasswordDemoProject/src/components/PasswordDemo.java)

Comment: the problem is, that all tutorials I see, don't have an example with a password which is already set. I set a password like "123" and just what to hide this

Comment: `don't have an example with a password which is already set` - yes well setting the password doesn't make any sense so I doubt you will find an example. In any case a JPasswordField is no different than any other JTextField. You use the setText() method,

Answer (score 0):

Passwords should always be encrypted via a hash for best security. It is the hash that would be stored. When a password is supplied by a User it should be automatically hashed using the same salt and compared to the same salted stored hash for validity. No one but the User should ever know what the true password might be.

What it looks like you are trying to do is create your own custom JOptionPane InputBox which the JOptionPane is designed to also accomplish. You would want to create a JPanel, add the components you want displayed with some layout information, then apply the JPanel to be displayed within say a **Confirm Dialog**. Here is how you might want to go about doing this:

```
private void customLoginInputBox() {
    // Create a dummy JFrame. This is done so that
    // the Dialog boxes that are used in the application
    // do not hide behind the IDE. Not a problem for
    // some. If you can't use 'this' as the component 
    // source for the JOptionPane then use the two code
    // lines below (otherwise remove them).
    final JFrame iFRAME = new JFrame();
    iFRAME.setAlwaysOnTop(true);

    String uName;
    String passWrd = "";

    // Get User input as to User Name and Password.
    // using a custom Input Dialog...
    // Build the Login dialog Panel...
    BorderLayout layout = new BorderLayout();
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(layout);
    JLabel label = new JLabel("<html>Please supply your Login information. If "
            + "you are<br>a New User then you will be automatically added<br>"
            + "to the database.<br><br><br></html>");
    panel.add(label, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    JPanel p = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(5, 5));
    JPanel labels = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1, 2, 2));
    labels.add(new JLabel("User Name:", SwingConstants.RIGHT));
    labels.add(new JLabel("Password:", SwingConstants.RIGHT));
    p.add(labels, BorderLayout.WEST);
    JPanel controls = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1, 2, 2));

    JTextField userName = new JTextField();
    controls.add(userName);

    JPasswordField password = new JPasswordField();
    controls.add(password);
    p.add(controls, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    panel.add(p);
    JLabel baseLabel = new JLabel("<html><pre><font size=2>                  "
            + "Select <font color=red>Cancel</font> to quit</font></pre><br></html>");
    panel.add(baseLabel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    // Get Input from User. This will display 
    // your custom Input Dialog Box.
    int res = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this, panel, "User Login ...",
            JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);

    // Process the result from our custom Input Dialog Box
    if (res == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION && !userName.getText().equals("")
            && !Arrays.toString(password.getPassword()).equals("")) {
        uName = userName.getText();
        char[] pass = password.getPassword();
        for (int i = 0; i < pass.length; i++) {
            passWrd += Character.toString(pass[i]);
        }

        // Do whatever you want with User Name and Password
        System.out.println("User Name Supplied:\t" + uName);
        System.out.println("Password Supplied :\t" + passWrd);
    }
    else {
        // Do whatever you want when nothing is supplied
        // or User selectes the Cancel button or simply 
        // closes the Input Box Dialog.
        System.out.println("Input Canceled!");
    }
}
```